# Front entrance door and timber frames leak water during heavy rain

Tags: front-door

Front timber door (south facing) seeps water through panels into the inside of the door. Adjacent timber frames also get wet. Is it just a case of non water proofed timber?

[image: whole front door]
[image: water coming through front door]
[image: timber frame damage]
[image: Front door from outside]
[image: outside window closeup]
[image: full front door picture]

Comment: hopefully you did not pay for that door

Comment: The windows probably need to be resealed with some caulking.  The door, have you thought about adding a storm/screen door to the outside.  An outside picture of the door/windows will help, since that is where the rain/water is coming from.

Comment: Give us pics of the *outside* too...  And yes, some caulking around the sidelights will help with that, and also make sure the wood is sealed too—on the frames and the door.

Comment: Thank you. Will add outside pictures. Appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0):

You already have starting water damage to that door and framing.

It will only get worse and rot quickly.

Suggest you install a awning.